# Simulating a customer line using linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a customer line showing customer number, wait times etc. I have three user inputs: Max simulation time, max interval between customer entries, and max service time.

ultimately, i would like to generate an output that looks like so:

[Line simulation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JdNu.png)

here's my code sofar, but im only able to generate the minutes but not the rest of the output.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Node {
public:
    Node() {};
    Node(int, int, int) {};
    //Node(int,int, int){}
    void SetCustEntryMinute(int custNum, int entryMinute, int servTimeRem) {

        entryMin = entryMinute;
        custNo = custNum;
        serviceTimeRemain = servTimeRem;
        next = NULL;
    }
    void SetNext(Node* aNext) { next = aNext; }
    int CustEntryMinute() { return entryMin; }
    int CustNum() { return custNo; }
    int ServTmRm() { return serviceTimeRemain; }
    Node* Next() { return next; }

    int custNo;
    int entryMin;
    int serviceTimeRemain;
    Node* next;
};


//List class
class List {
public:
    List() { /*head = NULL; tail = NULL; */};
    //void Print();
    void enqueue(int custNum, int entryMinute, int servTimeRem);
    void dequeue();
    Node *getHead() { return head; };
    Node* head;
    Node *tail;
};



/* Append a node to the linked list*/
void List::enqueue(int custNum, int entryMinute, int servTimeRem)
{

    // Create a new node
    Node* newNode = new Node(custNum, entryMinute, servTimeRem);

    // Create a temp pointer
    if (tail)
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    tail = newNode;

}



/* Serve a node from the list*/
void List::dequeue() {

    // Create a temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;
    //head = head->Next();

    // No nodes
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        //nothing to delete
        return;
    }
    if (head == tail)//only one node
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        head = head->next;
    }
    delete tmp;
}



int main()
{
    List list;
    int serviceTimeMax;
    int maxInterval;
    int timeCount = 0;
    int timeMax;
    int entryMinute = 0;

    cout << "Enter max time: ";
    cin >> timeMax;

    cout << "Enter max interval between two services: ";
    cin >> maxInterval;

    cout << "Enter max service time: ";
    cin >> serviceTimeMax;

    int custNum = 1;
    Node* personAhead = NULL;
    cout << "Minute \tCustomer\t Entry\t Service Time\t Wait time\t Minutes remaining\n";
    cout << "Number \tNumber  \tMinute\t Remaining\t Remaining\t until service is completed\n\n";
    int nextJobTime = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < timeMax + 1; i++) {
        if (i == nextJobTime)
        {
            list.enqueue(custNum, i, rand() % serviceTimeMax);
                nextJobTime = i + rand() % maxInterval;
        }
        Node *head = new Node;
        while (head != NULL) {
            if (head->serviceTimeRemain == 0)
            {
                list.dequeue();
                head = list.getHead();
            }

            Node *p = head;
            int wait_time = 0;
            cout << i << "\n";
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                wait_time += p->serviceTimeRemain;
                cout << "\t" << p->custNo << "\t" << p->entryMin << "\t" << wait_time << "\t" << wait_time + p->serviceTimeRemain << "\n";
                p->serviceTimeRemain--;
            }
        }


    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

At this point, it only generates the user entered time.

Comment: Since this looks like an assignment, I will give the following advice. Try running the code in a debugger. Single step the program. Does the real program flow follow your intended flow? Inspect the variables, do they have the correct value?

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` is a sign that Visual Studio is being used. Visual Studio has one of the best , if not the best, debuggers available. Learn to use it or you are doomed to spending far, far too much time on your assignments.

Comment: You put in some surplus code you could've omitted. You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Points taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting stuck in an infinite loop

```
while (p != NULL)
{
    wait_time += p->serviceTimeRemain;
    cout << "\t" << p->custNo << "\t" << p->entryMin << "\t" << wait_time << "\t" << wait_time + p->serviceTimeRemain << "\n";
    p->serviceTimeRemain--;
}
```

At no point do you alter `p`, which means you'll never exit the while loop.

Comment: alter p in what way? Do you mean increment the pointer or assign it to another pointer?

Comment: @Manny You continually process the same link. You need to advance `p` to the next link in the list.

Comment: Move to the next node in the list. `p = p->next;`

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification. points taken